# Cloud Spanner Emulator - docker initialization

Tags: google-cloud-spanner, google-cloud-spanner-emulator

I'm trying to setup a docker container that starts cloud spanner and that initializes it.

Using this official docker image provided by google: gcr.io/cloud-spanner-emulator/emulator

I'm looking to **automatically** initialize spanner on start.

I tried various things with the docker file, to summarize:

```
FROM gcr.io/cloud-spanner-emulator/emulator

RUN some gcloud command after to initialize local spanner db
```

But absence of informations on how this image works makes it hard to find if it's even possible to initialize it everytime the container starts.

I repeat myself, I need this to be run automatically when the container mounts. It's going to build pipelines.

Is there a way to do that with this provided docker image? Or should I create my own dockerfile that installs the emulator via gcloud cli?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a docker file example that allows to start docker emulator and to initialize with some custom gcloud commands

```
FROM google/cloud-sdk:slim

RUN apt-get install -y google-cloud-sdk google-cloud-sdk-spanner-emulator

COPY ./start_spanner.bash start_spanner.bash
COPY ./schema.ddl schema.ddl

CMD ./start_spanner.bash
```

Here is a sample content of file `start_spanner.bash`.

- See https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/ for details about `set -m` (job controls).
- See https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/emulator for info about how to use gcloud and emulator together

```
#!/bin/bash

set -m

gcloud beta emulators spanner start --host-port=0.0.0.0:9010 &

# configure gcloud cli to connect to emulator
gcloud config set auth/disable_credentials true
gcloud config set project someproject
gcloud config set api_endpoint_overrides/spanner http://localhost:9020/

# create spanner instance
gcloud spanner instances create someinstance \
  --config=emulator-config \
  --description="Test Instance" \
  --nodes=1

# create spanner database with the given schema
gcloud spanner databases create somedb \
 --instance=someinstance \
 --ddl-file=schema.ddl

fg %1
```

And the file `schema.ddl` is just your spanner ddl to run to create tables in the emulator as per spanner's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you wish to start up the Spanner emulator within a dockerfile.

You can create your own dockerfile to build the emulator.

Please utilize these [docker commands](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-spanner-emulator#via-pre-built-docker-image):

```
    docker pull gcr.io/cloud-spanner-emulator/emulator
    docker run -p 9010:9010 -p 9020:9020 gcr.io/cloud-spanner-emulator/emulator
```

To startup the spanner emulator.

EDIT:

With further clarification, it seems that what is being attempted is currently not an available feature of the official Docker image "gcr.io/cloud-spanner-emulator/emulator".

No documentation identifies how to utilize the official Spanner Emulator Docker image to run initialization scripts, neither the [GCP Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/emulator) nor the [Spanner emulator README](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-spanner-emulator/blob/master/README.md#quickstart). Such, as running gcloud commands on startup to create a spanner instance, upload a DDL file and add a database using said file.

The workaround identified by OP in the comments, seems to be the best solution as of now.

Comment: no that's not exactly what I want to do. I want to feed the docker's emulator instance with some scripts to run when it starts. Some docker images offer this feature where you can put files in a given directory of the container and the container will use them to initalize the service. But apparently that's not the case with this emulator image. And you cannot just prebuild it with your db already setup as it's in memory and it's erased everytime it restarts. Using docker commands won't help as this is for a build pipeline as I specified.

Comment: Apologies for not understanding exactly what you meant initially, could you explain further what type of scripts you wish to utilize, are you attempting to utilize the gcloud CLI to [initialize a spanner emulator gcloud configuration](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/emulator#using_the_gcloud_cli_with_the_emulator)?

Comment: So to be more specific, I want to create a Dockerfile extending this one. When it starts then it must *automatically* create an instance and a database+ddl of my choice. So that it is ready to use for my application. Without that it's hard to use it in build system because it's all in memory and it is reseted everytime container restarts. So I found a workaround  and use the official gcloud container https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/ to start spanner emulator alongside bash's job control as per https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification, we investigated this further and found that, this feature is not available on the official docker image for the Spanner emulator. I am glad you found the workaround, it seems to be the best means to achieve what you are looking for as of now.

Comment: @SoufianeGhzal I want to do the same thing. Can you share your Dockerfile?